# Integration testing for two components from different spring applications

Tags: spring, testing, integration-testing, spring-test

When we write test we have ability to specify only once the ContextConfiguration for test using @ContextConfiguration annotation.

How can we avoid clashing of dependencies in configurations from different applications?

For example we have two Applications 1 and 2 each having its own application contexts configurations. In real life they are working in different JVMs, but now we want to write integration test for two components one from the App1 and another from App2. Lets assume that we have two dependencies in comfiguration 1 and 2 that have the same id, how can we solve this issue?

Comment: Could you please clarify as currently your question is to vague...

Comment: Use constructor injection and pass separate mocks to the services.

Comment: Well, if the two components are deployed in separate applications in separate JVMs in production, how do they communicate: via web service calls, remoting, RMI, ...?